# Word-wrap when viewing source in WYGWAM

Tags: wygwam

I don't recall this previously being the case, but lately I've been accosted by horrendous long lines and the need to use a scroll bar when viewing raw source in a WYGWAM field. Is there any way to make this go away and have things soft-wrapped into a normal viewing port window?

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug with the latest CKEditor and Firefox.  I can reproduce it on their demo site http://ckeditor.com/demo, but only with Firefox.  Chrome and Safari seem to both work fine.

Comment: I agree that it just seems to be Firefox. I hadn't checked other browsers, just knew it wasn't right in the one I was using.

Comment: I tried wading through their bug tracker to see if it was a known issue, but without much luck. :(

Comment: Sorry, missed these responses. Should I turn to the CKEditor folk for a resolution on this, or is this a Firefox thing?

Comment: I'd probably start here first: https://dev.ckeditor.com/wiki/Bugs

Answer (score 0):

Not really a clean solution, but a functional work-around which I stumbled across in another forum...
Edit the file editor_gecko.css and look for a definition for .cke_source

Change the value from **white-space:pre;** to **white-space:pre-wrap!important;**
and wygwam will wrap content in the source view in Firefox as well.